# How to extract sound from a DVD movie to mp3

Tags: ubuntu, dvd, mp3, extract

I have some workout DVD's which I would like to listen to while on the park (I don't have a big living room).

What can I use to extract the sound from the movies, on a **Ubuntu** machine, and convert it to mp3, or any other format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to do this a couple of years ago and [followed this guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-rip-dvd-audio-to-mp3-or-ogg.html).

Basically, go to terminal (I still don't think it is in the add/remove programs) and type:

> `sudo apt-get install transcode`

Next type

> `transcode -i /dev/dvd -x dvd -T 1,-1 -a 0 -y raw -m audiotrack.mp3`

This should convert the whole disk to .mp3, if you read that guide, it goes in to a lot more detail and how to customise the command to do a whole lot more, such as single chapters.