# Can I make an Audio only copy of a DVD

Tags: dvd

Can I make an Audion only CD of a DVD?  I have an Eagles Live in Melbourne DVD that I cant find as a CD to use in the car (if I can Do I have to do anything differnet, I have not been able to get it to work so far)

Comment: Which format has that DVD?

Comment: There are different limitations between an Audio CD and a DVD. Keep in mind that an Audio CD has a maximum length of 74 minutes (or 80 minutes for some). If your concert has a longer duration, it will simply not fit. a DVD can be compressed to be longer with slightly less quality, something that is not possible with an Audio CD. If this is the case, check if your car stereo can handle MP3's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rip concert DVD to MP3](http://superuser.com/questions/386615/rip-concert-dvd-to-mp3), and/or [How to extract sound from a DVD movie to mp3](http://superuser.com/questions/95043/how-to-extract-sound-from-a-dvd-movie-to-mp3).

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial applications as [DVD Audio Extractor](http://www.dvdae.com/) that can do it easily.

Besides of that you can try doing it in a more manual way as they show in [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Rip-DVD-Audio-to-MP3-Using-VLC-Media-Player) that involves using Handbrake and VLC